# Why does my JavaScript object not see the following method?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    MyClass = function (id) {
    }

    MyClass.prototype.myFunc1 = function () {
        alert("myFunc1");
    }

    MyClass.prototype = {
        myFunc2:function () {
            alert("myFunc2");
        }
    }
    var myInstance = new MyClass({});
    myInstance.myFunc1();
</script>
</body>
</html>
​
```

Running the above I get the error message

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'myFunc1'

If I delete myFunc2 entirely the error message goes away.  What is happening here?

Comment: Please consider marking one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

There's an error because you override the prototype by assigning a new object to it - hence you're getting rid of `myFunc1`.

Do either:

```
MyClass.prototype.myFunc1 = function() {...}
MyClass.prototype.myFunc2 = function() {...}
```

OR

```
MyClass.prototype = {
    myFunc1: function() {...},
    myFunc2: function() {...}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First you change your object's prototype by adding `myFunc1`. Then you completely replace the prototype with a new one, and that removes `myFunc1`.

You can just swap the statements, so that `.prototype = ...` goes first. Then `myFunc1` will be **added** to the prototype where `myFunc2` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aB2hq/2/) (watch the console) and simple explanation

```
var MyClass = function(id) {}

//here you are adding to the prototype object
MyClass.prototype.myFunc1 = function() {
    alert("myFunc1");
}

//here, you replaced the whole prototype object with another object
MyClass.prototype = {
    myFunc2: function() {
        alert("myFunc2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one... It is working.

```
MyClass = function (id) {
}

MyClass.prototype = {
    myFunc2: function () {
        alert("myFunc2");
    }
}

MyClass.prototype.myFunc1 = function () {
    alert("myFunc1");
}

var myInstance = new MyClass({});
myInstance.myFunc1();
```